# Вопрос по сериализации объектов в java

Tags: java, исключения, наследование, сериализация, десериализация

Есть классы, расположенные в определённой иерархии наследования:

```
public class Program {
    public Program(){
        System.out.println("Текст");
    }
}

public class Wild extends Program{
    public Wild(){
        System.out.println("НеТекст");
    }
}

public class BasicProgramists extends Wild{
    public BasicProgramists(){
        System.out.println("Бесполезная программа");
    }
}

import java.io.*;

public class BasicUser extends BasicProgramists implements Serializable {
    public BasicUser(){
        System.out.println("Использование бесполезной программы");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicUser user = new BasicUser();
        System.out.println();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream or = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Progg.ser"));
            or.writeObject(user);
            or.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Progg.ser"));
            BasicUser user1 = (BasicUser) is.readObject();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

После компиляции получаем вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До отступа - результат работы конструктора BasicUser

После отступа - результат работы десериализации

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в результате десириализации, программа не выводит на экран результат работы конструктора BasicUser, хотя выводит результат работы всех родительских классов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42456236/4444092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сериализация в java не использует конструкторы для создания объектов. Поэтому контруктор не был вызван.

Но почему вызвались кострукторы родительских классов? Очевидно, т.к. они не реализовали `Serializable`, то механизм сериализации о них ничего не знал и поэтому инициализация происходила обычным способом - через конструктор.

В сказаном легко убедиться реализовав `Serializable` классом `Program`.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно, чтобы все конструкторы отрабатывали. Немного допилил ваш код:

```
import java.io.*;

class Program {
    Program() {
        System.out.println("Текст");
    }
}

class Wild extends Program {
    Wild() {
        System.out.println("НеТекст");
    }
}

class BasicProgrammers extends Wild {
    BasicProgrammers() {
        System.out.println("Бесполезная программа");
    }
}

class BasicUser extends BasicProgrammers {
    BasicUser() {
        System.out.println("Использование бесполезной программы");
    }
}

class SuperUser extends BasicUser implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperUser superUser = new SuperUser();
        System.out.println();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream or = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Progg.ser"));
            or.writeObject(superUser);
            or.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Progg.ser"));
            SuperUser superUser1 = (SuperUser) is.readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
// Текст
// НеТекст
// Бесполезная программа
// Использование бесполезной программы
//
// Текст
// НеТекст
// Бесполезная программа
// Использование бесполезной программы
//
// Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Можно ещё блок инициализации в `BasicUser` сделать как замена конструктора.

Comment: Подобно вашему примеру можно сделать класс-сериализатор с геттером на `BasicUser`.